# Shortcut Key to set focus on the new tab's search textbox

Tags: firefox, firefox-quantum

In the new Firefox Quantum in the new tab there's a search box. Is there a way to set the focus there so I can do Ctrl-T, Ctrl-(what goes here?) and start typing?